# ModuleNotFoundError on easyocr when running main.py

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror, easyocr

When i run my main.py on my python project, there is an error called,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\FYP Docs\Codes\New folder\Sidekick-S-TFG\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import FlowchartObjectDetection
  File "c:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\FYP Docs\Codes\New folder\Sidekick-S-TFG\FlowchartObjectDetection.py", line 5, in <module>
    from BlockDetection import detect_blocks
  File "c:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\FYP Docs\Codes\New folder\Sidekick-S-TFG\BlockDetection.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ocr import get_text
  File "c:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\FYP Docs\Codes\New folder\Sidekick-S-TFG\ocr.py", line 2, in <module>
    from OCR import EasyOCR, Tesseract, AzureOCR
  File "c:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\FYP Docs\Codes\New folder\Sidekick-S-TFG\OCR\EasyOCR.py", line 4, in <module>
    import easyocr
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'easyocr'
```

In requirement.txt, easyocr is already mentioned. Also, I run pip install easyocr and it was run without any error. This is my folder structure.

[image]

Comment: Which python binary are you using?  Are you using the same python environment that you installed easyocr to?

Comment: @ewokx Yes, same

Comment: how did you install easyocr?

Comment: please share the code you meet this error

Comment: @KanchanaKariyawasam, please show the code of your main.py

Comment: I was able to fix this error by updating my conda. The issue was with my conda.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this error by updating my conda. The issue was with my conda.